# Python, requests lib. The method is not allowed for the requested URL

Tags: python, json, rest

Пытаюсь внести нужные мне данные по API, POST-методом, но в конечном итоге получаю в выводе:

```
    https://www.zopim.com/api/v2/chats/shortcuts
{
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "description": "The method is not allowed for the requested URL."
}
```

На Python это имеет следующий код:

```
import json
import requests

login = '***'
password = '***'

endpoint_sc = '/api/v2/chats/shortcuts'

api_base_url = 'https://www.zopim.com'
end_point = f'{api_base_url}{endpoint_sc}'

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}

r = requests.post(end_point, data={'name': 'testname', 'message': 'testmsg', 'options': 'Yes/No'}, auth=(f'{login}', f'{password}'))
req_out = r.json()
print (r.url) ## Проверка урла

req_str = json.dumps(req_out, indent=4)

print(req_str)
```

При этом, пример из документации в баше работает https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/chat/shortcuts#create-shortcut :

```
curl https://www.zopim.com/api/v2/shortcuts \
  -d '{
        "name" : "intro",
        "message" : "Hi! Do you need assistance?",
        "options" : "Yes/No"
      }' \
  -v -u {email_address}:{password} \
  -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Я допускаю что причина находится в хедере, но что бы я не пробовал, увы, вывод идентичен. Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно видите где я ошибся? Также, пробовал отправлять data через json.dumps, вопрос это не решило.

Comment: `endpoint_sc = '/api/v2/chats/shortcuts'` и  `curl https://www.zopim.com/api/v2/shortcuts` найдите отличия ))) У вас неверный эндпоинт,  должен быть - `endpoint_sc = '/api/v2/shortcuts``

Comment: @SergBocharov А это суецыд. Спасибо больше =)